# Identify whether it's rest call or WCF call in ClientMessageInspector and ServerMessageInspecter

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

All,

I am having couple of WCF services and one rest service which uses ClientMessageInspector and ServerMessageInspector for token Authentication.
Is there any way to find out in  ClientMessageInspector and ServerMessageInspector whether request coming from WCF or REST

**Something like in ClientMessageInspector**

```cs
public class ClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector {
    public object BeforeSendRequest (ref Message request, IClientChannel channel) {
        if (request header is WCF) {
            // Do Something
        } else if (request header Rest) {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

**Something like in ServerMessageInspector**

```cs
public class ServerMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector {
    public object AfterReceiveRequest (ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext) {
        if (request header is WCF) {
            // Do Something
        } else if (request header Rest) {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding breakpoints, we can find that the request in Web HTTP binding is in stream mode. Try to check the type of request. is it a workaround?

Comment: @AbrahamQian... Thanks for the reply. would you please provide me sample piece of code for this please.

Comment: @AbrahamQian.. Would you please provide sample code for this, means how to check request binding is in stream mode?.

Comment: In non-streaming mode, the type of request is BufferedMessage. 
We can print the contents of the request variable directly, but under webhttpbinding, the type of request is that NullMessage, cannot be output directly.

Comment: if (request.GetType().Name=="NullMessage")
            {
            }
            else if(request.GetType().Name=="BufferedMessage")
            {
            }

Comment: @AbrahamQian... Thanks for the quick response, i will check and update you shorlty.

Comment: @AbrahamQian....Thanks Abraham, i am able to identify.... :-)

Comment: @AbrahamQian.. Thanks for you response, as suggested i am using below code 
    bool isWcfRest1 = request.ToString().Contains(". stream ."), this works fine in debug mode but i deploy application then it's not working. Kindly help me